# Getting rid of DirtyAreas from topology using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, topology

I did a script the part of which creates and validate topology for a certain layer. Then topology object is deleted. But when it comes to edit session if I want to create new object it is shown that layer has dirty areas. 
I tried to add lines like

```
arcpy.RepairGeometry_management(fc,"DELETE_NULL")
arcpy.AddSpatialIndex_management(fc)
arcpy.Integrate_management(fc,0.01)
```

But nothing works from script file or addin. The only solution is to launch tools listed above manually.
Is there any other way to remove dirty areas using code?

Here is the full code of my script.

```
import arcpy
import os

from arcpy import env
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
path = r"D:\Data\File.gdb\fd"
topologya = path + "\\Topol"
arcpy.CreateTopology_management(path,"Topol")
arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(topologya,"lines")
arcpy.ValidateTopology_management(topologya)
arcpy.Delete_management(topologya)

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Why do you do this, creating then deleting a topology without even adding a rule? Do you just want your 'lines' feature class to undergo the validation step (applying default cluster tolerance and adding vertices)? If you delete the topology, the dirty areas shouldn't be visible anymore, so could you please post a picture of what you see in ArcMap?

Comment: @GISGe I have deal with that using Integrate tool